# Google managed SSL Certificates with Nginx Ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

So I'm in the process of setting up multiple GKE clusters, and I'm restricted to using a wildcard domain certificate but my domain is two levels deep, so that won't work. So now I'm trying to use google managed certificates, which works, but only seems to work with the GCE ingress, not nginx.

According to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs which has worked assuming I'm using just a single ingress resource that provisions a L7(http) load balancer using GCE ingress. My question is, would it be possible to setup the nginx ingress controller to use these managed certificates?

From the nginx helm install, it provisions a L4(tcp) load balancer, and uses a deployment to run the pod that handles the nginx controller. But I can't seem to be able to set the L4 load balancer to use my globally reserved static IP. Whereas the L7 one works fine.

Any thoughts on how to get managed certs working with nginx ingress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. I was reserving a global IP address for the L4 load balancer using GCE ingress, which is not allowed, since TCP load balancing is regional only, unlike HTTP load balancing, which requires a global IP reserved, instead of a regional one. So from that, it was never resolving the DNS record to the right IP. Good to know that confusing caveat with the global vs regional IPs...

Comment: so are you finally able to set up Google's managed certificated with Nginx ingress? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No I was not able to do this via Google managed certs. I ended up using cert-manager app in GKE https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager

Comment: I finally found that it's possible. You've to use GKE ingress + Nginx Ingress

Comment: @GijoVarghese can you please describe your solution in more details? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @GijoVarghese How can you use GKE ingress + Nginx Ingress ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: As far as I can tell, you would have to setup both ingresses, with the GCP managed certificates set on the Google ingress which would then route to the nginx, which seems overly redundant. What I ended up doing was to only use nginx ingress and setup cert-manager within the cluster. Very cool kube app the uses LetsEncrypt or potentially other CA's to automatically maintain ceritifcates ( https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager ) kudos to maintainers of that project, its working great

Comment: To use GKE ingress + Nginx Ingress - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602352/2023941

Answer (score 0):

Google managed-certs are only supported for GKE External Ingress.
From https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs:

> Note: Google-managed SSL certificates aren't currently supported for
> internal HTTPS load balancers. For internal HTTPS load balancers, use
> self-managed SSL certificates.

Here are the limitations I encountered when using GKE ingress:

- You can use managed certs, but only for external ingress, internal ingresses are not supported
- Your VPC has to be configured [a certain way](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress) to use internal load balancing, which is very tedious.
- Firewalls cannot be configured to limit source ips, as this information is lost from the Google Front End to the VMs. They only see the load balancer's source ips.

If you only need a certificate for an external ingress, you can just declare an Ingress with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"`, setup [ExternalDNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) to create the CloudDNS records for you, and then attach a Managed Cert to the domain name like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: certificate-name
spec:
  domains:
    - domain-name1
    - domain-name2
```

This gives a you a domain attached to your service, with SSL, all using google cloud DNS and google load balancing.

If you need an internal service, it will be a bit trickier. I personally decided to completely ditch the GKE ingress, use `ingress-nginx` to setup a `LoadBalancer` service with an internal IP, and then setup the certs using `cert-manager`. You can refer to this [blog](https://pushbuildtestdeploy.com/how-to-run-an-internal-load-balancer-with-ssl-on-gke/) for the approach.