# Can I use Google Managed Certificate in Google Kubernetes engine with NGINX INGRESS Controller?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have a NGINX Ingress in my GKE. I want make my URL secure. But I unfortunately I am unable to achieve that via cert-manager. I see an option to create Managed Certificates. But I am not sure if there is an annotation that allow me to use google managed certificate in NGINX Ingress. Controller.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-https
  namespace: non-default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "managed-certificate"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-production"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-service
              servicePort: hello-port
          - path: "/kube"
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes
              servicePort: 80
```

When I create a certificate with cert-manager, certificate status is showing **"Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate"**

Comment: Nginx Ingress when deployed uses default TLS certificates which is giving you "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" 

Depending upon how you have installed via helm or manifests , please provide your certificates in the options given here

HELM : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#configuration

Manifests : https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/common/default-server-secret.yaml

Since you might have already deployed you can edit the secret also directly with the cert and key

Comment: if you are following here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs , make sure your cluster version is 1.16.5-gke.1 or higher. or using correct apiVersion

Comment: How did you deploy the cert-manager? Because it will give you a valid Let's encrypt certificate.

Comment: Google managed certificates are different than cert-manager generated certificates. When using cert manager certificates, which will work with nginx ingress controllers, you need to define the `tls` section of your ingress spec which maps host names to secret names and cert-manager will use the specified secret name to store the generated SSL certificate. Since you have done that, I suspect an issue with your cert-manager installation (or perhaps you haven't installed it at all, this is not installed out of box in GKE clusters).

Comment: That said, I share your original question. If you stripped out all the cert-manager cruft, is it possible to use Google Managed Certificates with an nginx kubernetes ingress controller (as opposed to the documented method specifying a global static IP).

Comment: @PaulWheeler Currently no: See: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl#specifying_certificates_for_your_ingress

Comment: @AalexGabi is technically correct, but people have gotten traefik working behind the GCE ingress:  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/369#issuecomment-743012823

Comment: But I couldn't get traefik to work that way.   But I used the same mechanism for nginx and got it to work.   So I posted an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using cert-manager is easier, but if you cannot use cert-manager for some reason, you can try this solution.   It sets up both a GCE ingress and an nginx ingress.   The GCE ingress is public, terminates the SSL but forwards to the private nginx ingress to do the routing.

```
helm3 install -f nginx-values.yaml ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

```
#nginx-values.yaml

controller:
  service:
    type: NodePort
    annotations:
      cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "backendconfig"}'
  admissionWebhooks:
    enabled: false
defaultBackend:
  enabled: true
```

And then create a BackendConfig and an Ingress to set up a LoadBalancer that'll talk to the nginx NodePort service.

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 300
  healthCheck:
    requestPath: /healthz
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: foo,bar
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: ingress-nginx-controller
    servicePort: 80
```

And then you can create a ManagedCertificate and an Ingress for foo and bar, and they'll share the same LoadBalancer.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  domains:
    - foo.example.com
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 5000
```

Remember that every time you create a new ManagedCertificate / Ingress pair, you'll have to modify the gce ingress manifest with the name of the cert in the `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates` annotation.

Comment: Super helpful, should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you add annotation `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "managed-certificate"` to Ingress class `nginx`, the site will be insecure and report "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate". That annotation only works for Ingress class `gce`.
The [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#prerequisites) say your "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" must be "gce".

For nginx, certificates must be added as a Kubernetes secret. This will lose the self-rotating feature of the google managed certificates that only work with Ingress of class `gce`.